# How to invoke a method in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I had the following code in my create action.
**tasks_comtroller.rb**

```
def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)
    @task.complete = false

     n=1
      loop do
        unless Task.find_by priority: n
          @task.priority=n
          break
        end
        n+=1
      end

    respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user) }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.js
    end
   end
  end
```

Then I took out some part I made a method inside my task model.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 def priority_increment
     n=1
      loop do
        unless Task.find_by priority: n
          @task.priority=n
          break
        end
        n+=1
      end
  end
end
```

How can I now correctly invoke this method from controller?

Comment: Thats really inefficient since each iteration has to do a database query - instead do `Task.order(:priority).first` and let the database do the work.

Comment: @max Can you provide an example how this code should've looked so I could accept your answer? I'm using this for priority incrementing.

Comment: @max I just don't completely understand your line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats really inefficient since each iteration has to do a database query - instead do `Task.order(:priority).first` and let the database do the work.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.heighest_priority
    # .try lets us handle the case where there 
    # are no Tasks gracefully
    p = Task.order(:priority).first.try(:priority)
    # return the highest + 1 or 1 if there are no tasks.
    p ? p + 1 : 1 
  end
end
```

Calling methods in ruby in exactly the same no matter where you are calling the function:

```
obj.some_method # in Ruby the parens are optional
obj.some_method(someArg)
obj.some_method(someArg) do
  # blocks are awesome.
end
```

Here we have a class method - we call it by `Task.heighest_priority`.

So lets refactor the create method to use our new method:

```
def create
  @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params) do |t|
    t.priority = Task.heighest_priority
    t.complete = false
  end
  if @task.save
     format.html { redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user) }
     format.js
   else
     format.html { render action: 'new' }
     format.js
   end
end
```

Comment: Highly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put that part of code into the model, you have to call `self` instead of the instance variable `@task` like so:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 def priority_increment
     n=1
      loop do
        unless Task.find_by priority: n
          self.priority=n
          break
        end
        n+=1
      end
  end
end
```

Afterwards you can call it on the task instance:

```
@task.priority_increment
```